# htaccess Rewrite Rule query string to url

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have following url:

```
www.example.com/profile?id=31
```

And I want to redirect it to :

```
www.example.com/profile/id/31
```

How can I do this ??

I tried using this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=31($|&)
RewriteRule ^www\.example\.com/profile$ /www.example.com/profile/id/31?&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

But it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below,

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)=(.+)
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://www.example.com/$1/$2/$3 [R=301,L,QSD]
```

I am using match groups so it will work for any value for given similar pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I will go for something like this let me know if it helps:

```
RewriteRule ^ profile/([0-9]+)/?$ /profile?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

what it does is explained widely in https://stackoverflow.com/a/20566547/6517383 and other answers in this post.